# react-zoom-pinch-pan useTransformEffect issue

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this error,

React Router caught the following error during render Error: Transform context must be placed inside TransformWrapper

I am attempting to use the following hook

```
`useTransformEffect(({ state, instance }) => {
    console.log(state); // { previousScale: 1, scale: 1, positionX: 0, positionY: 0 }

    return () => {
        // unmount
    };
});`
```

I am not sure what I am missing here? Simply including these lines of code causes the error and I am unsure how to provide the context to the TransformWrapper component.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this is more related to the use of the `react-zoom-pinch-pan` library. You will need to do something like this:

First, wrap your `Component` within a `TransformWrapper` as follows and then try using the `hook`.

```
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <TransformWrapper>
      <TransformComponent>
        <MyComponent/>
      </TransformComponent>
    </TransformWrapper>
  );
};
```

Now, try doing this:

```
const MyComponennt = () => {
  
  useTransformEffect(({ state, instance }) => {
    console.log(state); // { previousScale: 1, scale: 1, positionX: 0, positionY: 0 }

    return () => {
      // unmount
    };
  });

  return (...)
};
```